# Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Tags: android

I have added minimum sdk 16 and target sdk is 29 . My android studio version is 3.5.2 . And this issues is coming :
***Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)***
For this issues I could not find any solution . Please help me out from this issues.

Comment: I have added android{
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

Answer (score 7):

Probably some method you are using needs the lvl 26 API and the minimum supported is 16 or you missing the compile options to java version.

Feel free to try:

- Add compile options to the gradle file

```
android{
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

or

- Change the minimum sdk for 26.

or

- Search where is this error and switch to a codecompatible with API 16